# Unix awk to replace inner single quote with inverted question mark

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to replace the inner single quote (ignoring the outer single quote) with an inverted question mark (¿). I am using below `awk` command, but it's not working. Semicolon is the separator character.

```
awk -F "'" -v OFS="'" '{for  (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub("'","\302\277", $i } 1' filename
```

And the data is:

```
'gasg'dhsh';'dhdjs'
```

Comment: Please show the input and expected output.  I'm nut sure I know what is meant by "turning around a question mark".  Also, since you use `'` as a delimiter, the data, once you parse it, will not contain any `'`.

Comment: ... and the `'` in the argument to `gsub()` will end the text of the `awk` program, since the program is single quoted.

Comment: Turn around question mark means mirror image of questions mark

Answer (score 1):

To replace all single quotes that are flanked by words with `¿` in a file (assuming `bash` is used, so that we may use `$'...'`):

```
q=$'\302\277'
sed "s/\>'\</$q/g" file
```

Alternatively

```
q=$( printf '\302\277' )
sed "s/\>'\</$q/g" file
```

or

```
sed "s/\>'\</¿/g" file
```

With the given input, this would produce

```
'gasg¿dhsh';'dhdjs'
```

The pattern `\>'\<` would match any `'` that has a word character immediately before and after.  The `;` character and start/end of line are not word characters, while both `g` and `d` are.

---

Your code has three main issues:

1. A single quoted string in the shell may never contain a single quote. The embedded single quote in the call to `gsub()` will end the single quoted string that is the `awk` code, producing a syntax error.
2. Setting the input field separator to a single quote using `-F "'"` will cause `awk` to split the input on all single quotes.  This means that the `awk` program will *never* see any single quotes, and your `gsub()` will therefore never replace anything.
3. The string `\302\277` is not an inverted question mark, unless interpreted as an escape sequence.

Correcting all of these issues would make the program work, but it would replace all occurrences of single quotes:

```
$ awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) gsub("'"'"'", sprintf("\302\277"), $i); print }' file
¿gasg¿dhsh¿;¿dhdjs¿
```

Comment: Why do you need `$'\302\277'` in bash? Isn't a simple `¿` better? It does not assume utf-8.

Comment: @Isaac I'll rephrase my previous comment. It's definitely possible to do that. I have added that as an alternative. I had issues pasting in a `¿` in the terminal I was working at while initially writing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "Inner single quote" you imply that there are "outer single quotes" and also assuming that those outer qoutes are at the start and end of each field (delimited by ";" ín this case) you can use:

```
$ awk -F ';' '{OFS=FS;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){gsub(q,i,$j);sub("^"i,q,$j);sub(i"$",q,$j)}}{print}' q='\047' i='¿'
'gasg¿dhsh';'dhdjs'
```